# Symfony2 - 301 redirects for article posts

Tags: symfony, redirect, routes, http-status-code-301

I'm fairly new to Symfony2 and redirects, I am trying to move posts from an articles section into a new section of a website.

Also, do I just leave the original articles as they (as they are indexed with Google's SEO) are in the MySQL database and create new versions of them in the new section?

E.g.,

original location:

`http://example.com/articles`

`http://example.com/articles/this-is-article-1`

new location:

`http://exmaple.com/`

`http://example.com/this-is-article-1`

I've come across the following in the Symfony2 Cookbook but I am unsure which one I would use.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to keep your old routing and add new route in your routing yml or annotation to point to the same action in your controller, this way you keep your old routing to articles which are SEO indexed and use your new routes in your twigs so that they get indexed with time, when you feel the need you don't need the old routing you can delete them when the new routes get better SEO.

Another solution which is redirecting as you asked is this :

## routing.yml

```
root:
    path: /articles
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: new_route_name_articles_index
        permanent: true
```

This will redirect your http://example.com/articles to your new routing that you created

Comment: So with re-directing, essentially when someone goes to `example.com/articles` they are redirected to `example.com`? Essentially, I am going to hide the /articles section in the layout and move all content over to the / home section. With that said do I need to move all the article posts from /articles to the / section? Would I need to recreate the posts for this?

Comment: @purpledot yes, and what do you mean by moving them? the articles are not really in /articles they are in database you can call them with your indexAction anywhere you want, it depends on which route you give. so if you redirect /articles to / then they will show at your root  example.com

Comment: Ok, with how it's setup up I have a / section for home which has it's own entity and posts, and /articles section with it's own entity and posts. How would I merge this for one list when displaying it in Twig? Unless I'm completely misunderstanding you.

Comment: Now you lost me lol, i thought you only wanted to change routing so that it redirects not merging anything

Comment: Well yes, I want redirect the existing routes from articles to the home so that the SEO isn't lost. However, they also need to appear on the home page as well as the articles section is going away.

Comment: now i got it, you want to display the articles in the homepage then? you need to change your homepage twig to meet your requirements , either you use {% render %} to render controller  {% render(controller( "YourBundle:Article:index")) %} in some part of your homepage twig this will put all the article page inside your home it basically go to your indexaction of articles return the twig of that action and append it in homepage

Comment: Got it, will try it. Back to the redirect question, will this redirect all posts to home? E.g, /articles/article-1, article-2 etc. I noticed in your example you are list just the /articles path.

Comment: no what i gave in my answer is an example how to redirect your /articles to a new path /blabla that you create or to your  home you put whatever route name it redirects to it. you will not see your articles anymore until you use your new route to render your articles, what redirect do is if i type /articles it will just be as i typed /home (if /home is the new route) thats all. You can add another configuration for article-1 etc.. to redirect to another route of your choice.

Comment: I see. I guess what I not understanding is how you would transfer the SEO from /articles/example-post to /example-post. If that is even possible?

Comment: How do you handle the SEO? or are you talking about links that are already showing in google for example? for those you can only redirect them as i said, then as you wont use those routes in twig anymore showing nowhere in the website google will start indexing those new routes and replacing the old ones. this is also related to your sitemap.xml i guess, i am not expert at SEO but this is a start to look it up for more informations

Comment: Yes, the article links already showing up in Google already. Thanks for all this info, I learned a bit from this.